# Removing Parent XML element from XML Serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class named Node and inside that i have Property of Type Document Class.

When I serialize it into XML, I get the output as

```
<Node>
<DocumentType>
<File></File>
</DoumentType>
<Node>
```

But I want the output as

```
<Node>
<File></File>
<Node>
```

Object Code

```
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "file")]
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public Document NodeDocument
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

How can I do that using C# xml Serialization?

Comment: DocumentType sounds like it describes the Node Element so why not set it as an attribute instead using `[XmlAttribute]`. `<Node DocumentType="test">`

Comment: Can you post the objects code? There are alternative document types to `File` presumably? Is `DocumentType` an array?

Answer (score 1):

Following Kami's suggestion, here is the code for your reference. All credit goes to Kami.

```
public class Node : IXmlSerializable {

    public Node() {
        NodeDocument = new Document();
    }

    public Document NodeDocument { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {            
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        NodeDocument.File = reader.ReadString();
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteStartElement("file");
        writer.WriteString(NodeDocument.File);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

public class Document {
    public String File { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var node = new Node();
        node.NodeDocument.File = "bbb.txt";

        Serialize<Node>("a.xml", node);

        node = Deserialize<Node>("a.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(node.NodeDocument.File);

        Console.Read();
    }

    static T Deserialize<T>(String xmlFilePath) where T : class {
        using (var textReader = File.OpenText(xmlFilePath)) {
            using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(textReader)) {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Serialize<T>(String xmlFilePath, T obj) where T : class {
        using (var textWriter = File.CreateText(xmlFilePath)) {
            using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter)) {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I also have other properties that I need to export to XML. Which are not string. They may be List,boolean, or an another class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing `IXmlSerializable` interface - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx.

You should then be able to write custom serialization/deserialization to facilitate the above.